# Multiple database directories with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I installed postgresql from source on Ubuntu 14.0.4. It is located in `/usr/local/pgsql`. At first, I created a data directory at `/usr/local/pgsql/data` and then ran

```
initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

I noticed inside this directory was a `postgresql.conf`.

Later I decided I wanted to put the data directory in the `/var` directory, since it is variable data. So I created a directory at `/var/local/postgresql/9.4.2/main` (I guess I should have named it data, but when using the repositories it uses main and I decided to follow that). Then I ran `initdb` again but this time specifying a new data directory:

```
initdb -D /var/local/postgresql/9.4.2/main
```

And pretty much it created the same data files as it did before, including the `postgresql.conf`. This time I opened up the `postgresql.conf` at `/var/local/postgresql/9.4.2/main` and gave it a default data directory:

```
data_directory = '/var/local/postgresql/9.4.2/main'
```

Now, at this point I wanted to start the postmaster daemon but I want the daemon to read the data directory from `/var/local/postgresql/9.4.2/main` rather than me specifying it as a flag. Unfortunately, it doesn't work:

```
$ pg_ctl start
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: out of curiosity, why install from source? Postgres provide [packages](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) for 14.04 and 9.4

Comment: @JackDouglas wouldn't it be easier to upgrade in the future when installed from source? Or am I wrong? Is there any benefits from installing from source over the repositories? I already installed from repositories before. Now I was trying something different.

Comment: I would have thought upgrading would be harder from source, but it depends on your skills I suppose (I assume you mean a major version upgrade). Are you planning to recompile every time there is a security fix? That's much easier using the repos, just `apt-get upgrade`..

Answer (score 1):

I got this working without specifying database directory, but you do need to specify the configuration file, so that the pg_ctl binary will know which data directory to use. So for example:

```
pg_ctl -D /etc/postgresql/9.4.2/main start
```

Comment: `.../9.4.2/...`? That's very uncommon. Typically, the minor version would **not** be included, you are not going to move the DB dir with every minor upgrade, so just: `.../9.4/...` Mistakes like this one sneak in when "brewing your own", which is the best example for why the packages are useful.

Comment: @Donato could you please accept your answer as the solution?  This way the question wouldn't pop up from time to time as unanswered.